# how to upload multiple images and preview all uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4

this code is working for single image, but i need to do that multiple , so help me to change this code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div><img id="img1" src="" alt="your image" style="max-width:180px;" /><output id=”result” ></div>
                    <div><input id="img11" onchange="readURL(this);" type="file"  name="Image1" id="" style="padding:10px; background:#2d2d2d;" ></div>
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                    <div><img id="img2" src="" alt="your image" style="max-width:180px;" /><output id=”result” ></div>
                    <div><input id="img22" onchange="readURL(this);" type="file"  name="Image1" id="" style="padding:10px; background:#2d2d2d;" ></div>
                </div>


            </div
```

Comment: Why? What's the reason you can't do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select multiple image files and show it on dom ! then you can do something like this: 
I guess this is what you are looking for

HTML:

```
<input type="file" multiple id="gallery-photo-add">
<div class="gallery"></div>
```

JS:

```
<script>

$(function() {
    // Multiple images preview in browser
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;

            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }

    };

    $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
        imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: its working, but input value get only first images data only, what to do fix that

Comment: which input value ? please describe. 

you have an array of selected file in input.files